# How to use boto mws to pull Amazon specific orderdata

Tags: python, boto, amazon-mws

I'm trying to figure out how to use boto to pull various Amazon seller account data. However, I seem not to be able to find any examples related to this.
The following code doesn't return an error, but neither does it return any useful data (except the commented out print orders line, that seem to return useful data).

```
from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection 

merchantId = 'zzzz' 
marketplaceId = 'zzz' 
accessKeyId = 'zzzz' 
secretKey = 'secret' 

mws = MWSConnection(accessKeyId, secretKey, Merchant=merchantId) 

orders = mws.list_orders(CreatedAfter='2015-10-23T12:00:00Z', MarketplaceId = 
[marketplaceId])
#print orders

theData = mws.get_order(AmazonOrderId='xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx')

print theData
```

Any hints on how to get hold of a particular orders associated data above?

Answer (score 3):

your `orders` variable looks good, that is why printing shows data, but its probably hard to understand.  From what I see boto creates custom objects which are translated from the web responses.  The most useful documentation are the [Amazon MWS Dev Guide](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_Overview.html) and the [boto mws documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/mws.html#).  If you look you will see that all the methods fit together.

The issue with your code is that your `list_orders` request returns a list of orders.  You need to parse the list to get the ID of each order.  The `get_order` call is then redundant since the `list_orders` method already returns order info.

The following code should work although haven't tested.

```
from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection 

merchantId = 'zzzz' 
marketplaceId = 'zzz' 
accessKeyId = 'zzzz' 
secretKey = 'secret' 

mws = MWSConnection(accessKeyId, secretKey, Merchant=merchantId) 

orders = mws.list_orders(CreatedAfter='2015-10-23T12:00:00Z', MarketplaceId = 
[marketplaceId])

for order in orders.ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order:
    this_order_id = order.AmazonOrderId
    theData = mws.get_order(AmazonOrderId = this_order_id)
    print theData
    #do what you want with the data
    #
    #EXAMPLE GET ORDER ITEMS
    order_items = mws.list_order_items(AmazonOrderId = this_order_id)
    print order_items
```